# ruby include vs extend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, railscasts

I am trying to abstract some of the logic required for cropping images into a module so that its not messing up my models. The code is based on http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

```
module CroppableImage
  def croppable_image(*image_names)
    image_names.each do |image_name|

      define_method "#{image_name}_sizes" do
        { :cropped => read_attribute("#{image_name}_size").to_s, :large => "800x800>" }
      end

      define_method "#{image_name}_geometry" do |style|
        style ||= :original
        @geometry ||= {}
        @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(eval "#{image_name}.path(style)")
      end

      define_method "#{image_name}_aspect_ratio" do
        width, height = read_attribute("#{image_name}_size").split("x")
        width.to_f / height.to_f
      end

      private

        define_method "reprocess_#{image_name}" do
          eval "#{image_name}.reprocess!"
        end

    end
  end

end
```

To include this into my model it seems that I have to use extend. I thought extend was for including class methods. I am from a java background - I thought using extend basically created static method on the class.

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend CroppableImage
  croppable_image :logo, :footer_image
```

-- this works

It seems then that what I am really wanting is to create instance methods.

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CroppableImage
  croppable_image :logo, :footer_image
```

-- This throws the error "undefined method `croppable_image' for #"

Can anyone please explain whats going on and if I should be using include or extend in this case. Thanks guys

Comment: `extend` adds the methods as class methods, while `include` adds the methods as instance methods.

Answer (score 14):

`extend M` internally is similar to `class << self; include M; end` - `extend` includes module into singleton class of an object (and makes instance methods of the module to be a singleton methods of a class you extend).

In your case you call `croppable_image` *in the context of a class definition* and thus `croppable_image` should be an instance method of a `Class` class or a singleton method of `Website` class.

This is why you should extend `Website` class with a module `CroppableImage` by using **extend CroppableImage** - it adds instance method `croppable_image` as a singleton method of `Website` class.

Comment: I think I finally get it. croppable_image is a class method but the methods that are defined with define_method become instance methods. I just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302789/can-i-define-method-in-rails-models and it all makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nick, Yes, `define_method` is executed on the class `Website` and `define_method` adds *instance methods* of the class `Website`.

Answer (score 7):

you can use both logic together.
Ruby has callbacks for extend and include
Example of using included callback

```
module CroppableImage
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def bar
      puts 'class method'
    end
  end

  def foo
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end
```

Comment: a slick way to do it ;)